# Swagger 3.x : Query params act as readonly values

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I tried swagger 3.2.2 by running a GET operation with few query params. 
I find defaults values I set in REST API can't override in swagger UI.  All the text boxes are read only, and drop-down of Boolean query param always sends 'false' though I select it to 'true'.  It seems program default values are super hard-corded here.  I was playing with swagger @ApiPram(..) to fix this but it didn't help me.

Did anyone ran in to the same issue I describe above with Swagger 3.x?

Comment: Try the latest version of Swagger UI (3.5.0). Also, post the contents of your spec (YAML or JSON file).

Comment: Thanks @Helen 3.5.0 did fix my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start using Swagger UI **3.5.0** and fixed the issue